# jQuery or Javascript to grab submit form data and update ID text

Tags: jquery, html

UPDATED:

-removed the . in front of alertText 
-updated the jQuery now being used, but still not working.

---

The goal is for the user to type something into the alert text field and have that update the alertText class, the current function is just trying to change the inner html on button click of the submit form because I can't even get that to work at the moment.

Hello I'm trying to make a form that enables someone to update a P ID text line when submitted.  I'm having a little trouble understanding how to grab the submitted text with jQuery in order to change the inner html of an ID tag.

Here is my HTML Doc,  I'm trying to update .alertText with whatever the user submits...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
</head>
<body id="menuStyle">

       <h1 class="title">Alerts</h1>

 <form id="alertForm">
 Alert:<br>
  <input type="text" name="alertInput" id="alertInpit">
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="alertPass" id="alertPass">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="subNow">
  </form>
  <!-- change me -->
       <p class="alertText"> </p>

   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

       <script src="js/alert.js"></script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Here is the jQuery I've started for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var changeAlert = document.querySelector(".alertText");

/*
$('#alertForm').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    this.submit(); 
});*/

$( "#subNow" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    changeAlert.innerHTML = "This is now updated";
});

});
```

Comment: You need to just prevent the default action of the button click ... like `$("#subNow").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeAlert.innerHTML = "This is now updated";

});`

Comment: Try removing `.` at `<p class=".alertText"> </p>`

Comment: Also class attribute should not have `.` so `<p class="alertText"></p>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q88L2wtL/

Comment: Ill try that - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to update .alertText with whatever the user submits...

Try using `event.preventDefault()` within `click` event , `.serializeArray()` to return name , value of `input` child elements of `form` , `Array.prototype.map()` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body id="menuStyle">

  <h1 class="title">Alerts</h1>

  <form id="alertForm">
    Alert:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="alertInput" id="alertInpit">
    <br>Password:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="alertPass" id="alertPass">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="subNow">
  </form>
  <!-- change me -->
  <p class="alertText"></p>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var changeAlert = document.querySelector(".alertText");

      $("#subNow").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var res = $("form").serializeArray().map(function(input) {
          return input.name + ":" + input.value
        }).join(" ");
        changeAlert.innerHTML = res;

      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice, this works well.  Is it possible for me to put a password on this?  I see its using ajax.

Comment: _"Is it possible for me to put a password on this?"_  Not certain interpret correctly ? _"I see its using ajax."_ `ajax` not used at `js` at post , `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` loads jQuery into `window` , `document`

Comment: if I place <p class="alertText"></p>  on a different webpage, for example index.html  -  will it still be able to change the text?

Comment: Would `form` be at different `html` document than "index.html" ? Tried dynamically loading , opening "index.html" at `form` `click` with `<p class="alertText"></p>` text set to `form` value ?

Comment: Yes index.html and alert.html, where the form is inside alert.html.  I realized that even if I get alert.html to update the text on index.html it will not stay updated.  Every time the page is loaded the default values of p class="alertText"> equalling nothing are loaded back.

Answer (score 1):

".alertText" -> "alertText" is fixed in Question.

Also change

```
$("#subNow").click(function() { ... }
```

to

```
$("#subNow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(".alertText")[0].innerHTML = "This is now updated"
})
```

and it should work.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AcPgFVT9DR8NsBMpZZBM?p=preview)